# How to pass or reference item from ng-repeat to another element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to pass a single item/object ('ca') from a repeater to another element (in this case a modal) within the same controller context:

```
<div data-ng-controller="ContactActionCtrl" data-ng-app="myApp" runat="server">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h2>Tasks</h2>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Due</th>
                    <th>Completed</th>
                    <th>Created By</th>
                    <th>Assigned</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="ca in contactactions | filter:{ObjectType:'Task'}">
                <tr data-actionid="{{ca.Id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionDetail">
                    <td>{{ca.CreationDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
                    <td>{{ca.ActionDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</td>
                    <td>{{ca.CompletionDate | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
                    <td>{{ca.CreatedByUsername}}</td>
                    <td>{{ca.UserIDUsername}}</td>
                    <td><label data-ng-if="ca.ActionType">{{ca.ActionType}} - </label><label>{{ca.ActionDescription}}</label><br>{{ca.CreationNotes | limitTo:270}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="actionDetail" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{ca.ActionDescription}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                //more details from ca here
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything is working, including popping up the bootstrap modal div from a row click, except for actually populating it from outside of the repeater.  Since the full object is still in memory, I was hoping to avoid fetching a singular item from the db again (with a different service call) in order to fill the modal.  Even though I'm showing a modal, I think this question might apply to any element / set of elements that lie outside the repeater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straight forward way for you would be to have the modal display a different single variable e.g. 'ca.selectedItem' then when you click on an item populate selectedItem with that object.  I'll see if I can whip up an example.

Controller:

```
$scope.contactActions = [{name:"Action 1"},{name:"Action 2"},{name:"Action 3"}] 
$scope.selectedAction = {name:""};

$scope.rowClick = function(event, selected) {
  $scope.selectedAction = selected;
};
```

Markup:

```
<tr data-actionid="{{ca.Id}}" ng-click="ca.rowClick($event, i)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionDetail">
```

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/FswHCN).

P.S. You can use bootstrap with Angular but it uses non-angular javascript (i.e. jquery) which bypasses Angular to do things like DOM manipulation.  This often results in Angular not updating it's bindings properly, so you end up doing stuff like $scope.apply() to manually tell Angular to update all it's bindings.  One alternative to this would be to use [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which uses the same css but the javascript has been re-implemented in Angular.

Comment: Thank you!  While your plunk didn't exactly match the example above, I got the gist of it and made it happen.  I use the new scope item, selectedAction, in the modal.  Wonderful.  Welcome to SO too!

Comment: good thing about it is that, it does shallow copying. Which means if you update anything in this newly copied object, it will be reflected upon same item that it was initiated from.
And if you want deep copying, then angular.copy(selected, newItem) will do the trick since it does deep copy!